# Why .net method invocation lost in windows powershell logging?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, logging, event-log

I enabled the powershell mudole, script block logging and transcription in group policy in Windows 10, as the method here, https://www.rootusers.com/enable-and-configure-module-script-block-and-transcription-logging-in-windows-powershell/ .

And I have a ps1 script as followed, with 2 statments:

```
$rep = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")
$t = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystemProduct  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UUID
```

After running the script, I find the call to 'GetHostAddresses' was not record, and only the second statement in the powershell logging. Could anyone help me on how to log the event by calling .Net module method ? Beside the powershell logging, any other methods is ok.

Comment: Beware the same activity may be split over multiple event log messages

Comment: But I checked all the logs, nothing about that, even splited